# update to 22.6.2 or above required but already installed?

Tags: auto-update

Today I've installed this (Google Play Services):
[image]

After that all my java-files look like this:

[image]

My preferences show me this:

[image]

Help > About ADT shows this:

[image]

Trying to update I get this:

[image]

My SDK Manager shows me this:

[image]

I'm completely at a loss and don't know what's happened there. It worked properly before installing Google Play services.